# When would I use a Hybrid flow with response_type=code id_token token in OpenID Connect?

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

I have been reading about OpenId Connect and their flows that are **implicit flow**, **authorization code flow** and **hybrid flow**.

I know that for example, the implicit flow is kind of insecure and should be used just in public clients like SPA application.

Now I´m trying to understand the Hybrid Flow that can be used for non-public applications like .Net MVC applications where you have a backchannel communication and thus you can save a secret password.

Reading about the Hybrid flow I know that it has 3 different types of response_type that can be:

1. code id_token
2. code token
3. code id_token token

For me, the best response_type would be code id_token where I can get the code in the front channel and then send that code to the Identity Server Provider and get the access token through the backchannel.

I've been searching for information on a real-world application of **response_type=code id_token token**, or **code token**, but other than reading that in these flows the first token/s are issued by the authorization endpoint which is the front channel and the final tokens that are issued by exchanging the authorization code are issued at the token endpoint, which is the backchannel and thus inherently accepted as being more secure, I fail to understand what you would use this for. Any information would be gladly accepted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why hybrid flow? The oft-documented rationale is that your app can immediately have info about the user via the id_token while the access token acquisition is still in flight. Technically this is true but it's still rarely used in the wild.

One real-world example is a Financial-grade API (FAPI) profile developed by a working group under the umbrella of OpenID Foundation. It recommends hybrid flow for security reasons. It's worth noting that the channel split "feature" of the flow is not enough on its own to provide the desired security properties, more "cooperation" from other moving parts is needed. From [FAPI implementer's draft part 2](https://openid.net/specs/openid-financial-api-part-2-ID2.html):

> This profile describes security provisions for the server and client
>   that are appropriate for Financial-grade APIs by defining the measures
>   to mitigate:
>
> - attacks that leverage the weak binding of endpoints in [RFC6749] (e.g. malicious endpoint attacks, IdP mix-up attacks),
> - attacks that modify authorization requests and responses unprotected in [RFC6749] by leveraging OpenID Connect's Hybrid Flow that returns
>     an ID Token in the authorization response.

and details

> 8.3.3 Identity provider (IdP) mix-up attack
>
> In this attack, the client has
>   registered multiple IdPs and one of them is a rogue IdP that returns
>   the same `client_id` that belongs to one of the honest IdPs. When a user
>   clicks on a malicious link or visits a compromised site, an
>   authorization request is sent to the rogue IdP. The rogue IdP then
>   redirects the client to the honest IdP that has the same `client_id`. If
>   the user is already logged on at the honest IdP, then the
>   authentication may be skipped and a code is generated and returned to
>   the client. Since the client was interacting with the rogue IdP, the
>   code is sent to the rogue IdP's token endpoint. At the point, the
>   attacker has a valid code that can be exchanged for an access token at
>   the honest IdP.
>
> This is mitigated by the use of OpenID Connect Hybrid Flow in which
>   the honest IdP's issuer identifier is included as the value of `iss`.
>   The client then sends the code to the token endpoint that is
>   associated with the issuer identifier thus it will not get to the
>   attacker.
>
> 8.4.3.  Authorization response parameter injection attack
>
> This attack occurs when the victim and attacker use the same relying party client.
>   The attacker is somehow able to capture the authorization code and
>   state from the victim's authorization response and uses them in his
>   own authorization response.
>
> This can be mitigated by using OpenID Connect Hybrid Flow where the
>   `c_hash`, `at_hash`, and `s_hash` can be used to verify the validity of the
>   authorization code, access token, and state parameters. The server can
>   verify that the state is the same as what was stored in the browser
>   session at the time of the authorization request.

For a more technical description of these two attacks and countermeasures, see [Single Sign-On Security – An Evaluation of OpenID Connect](https://www.nds.rub.de/media/ei/veroeffentlichungen/2017/01/30/oidc-security.pdf)

For a realllly detailed description, take a look at [OIDC Security Analysis](https://arxiv.org/abs/1704.08539) paper.

Answer (score 0):

The hybrid flow allows the backend to continue to act on the user’s behalf in an offline way (when the user is no longer present sending requests by browser) or independently of the frontend... doing other stuff in parallel. It can use the back channel exchanged refresh token to continue to get a new access token and work indefinitely.